# How can I simply verify that a username and password are correct with Devise and Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am using `Devise` and `Rails 3`.

I want to call a function that will simply verify that a user's `username` and password combination is correct without actually logging in that user. Is there some way I can accomplish something like this with Devise:

```
User.authenticate(params[:username], params[:password])
```

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Get the user out of the database:

```
user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
```

Then you can check their password with:

```
user.valid_password?(params[:password])
```

Comment: Make sure you create a 'user' variable on the first line of code, so that the second line can use it: user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])

Comment: Awesome, that's what i was looking for

Comment: If `params[:password]` is nil in your session controller, check `params[:user][:password]`

Comment: [RubyDoc link](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/DatabaseAuthenticatable#valid_password%3F-instance_method)

Answer (score 4):

Or using the one liner:

```
User.find_by_email(params[:email]).try(:valid_password?, params[:password])
```

which returns `true` or `nil`

Answer (score 1):

### Official Devise Way

Devise has two [built-in methods](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Find-a-user-when-you-have-their-credentials) that let you do exactly this:

```
user = User.find_for_authentication(username: params[:username])
user.valid_password?(params[:password])
```

Answer (score -9):

well, Devise makes it automatically: when user sumbits login information, then it makes that check for you.

if you want more control, then you have 2 choices:

1- look at Devise sources finding where it makes that check

2- write your own login system (it's not that hard as you can think)

Comment: It turns out that if the devise model (in my case, Person) has :database_authenticatable, then it creates a method called Person#valid_password?(password) that can be used to verify credentials. Pretty snazzy.