# Given plain text email and password, how to check if a User exists with those credentials?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Can't just do `User.where(:email => email, :password => password)` since passwords aren't stored in plain text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Get the user out of the database:
>
> User.find_by_email(params[:email])
>   Then you can check their password
>   with:
>
> user.valid_password?(params[:password])

From [How can I simply verify that a username and password are correct with Devise and Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263291/how-can-i-simply-verify-that-a-username-and-password-are-correct-with-devise-and/6245020#6245020)